# Telerik RadGrid Update Command not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

So, I have a RadGrid with a typical edit arrangement that was working... and now isn't.  Never firing the UpdateCommand event, set a breakpoint there and it's not being reached.  Making me crazy because it had been working just fine and I can't think of anything I've done that would cause it. When I click edit, the form opens just fine, the cancel button works but the update command never fires.
In the grid I have:

```
OnUpdateCommand="pendingVehiclesRadGrid_UpdateCommand" 

And in my code behind I have:

 protected void pendingVehiclesRadGrid_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
blah blah
}
```

Seems pretty straightforward but as I say... nothing.  I'd be, as always, deeply grateful if someone with fresh eyes can make a suggestion.

Edit to add XML:

```
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="pendingVehiclesRadGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" 
       DataMember="ID" 
             onneeddatasource="pendingVehiclesRadGrid_NeedDataSource"
            OnUpdateCommand="pendingVehiclesRadGrid_UpdateCommand" PageSize="20" 
            onitemcommand="pendingVehiclesRadGrid_ItemCommand" >
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="status,charity,make,model,year,vin,date,id,salePrice,bid,note" 
            EditMode="EditForms">

<CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>

<RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</RowIndicatorColumn>

<ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</ExpandCollapseColumn>

    <Columns>
    <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="History" Text="History" UniqueName="detailBtn" HeaderText="History" HeaderButtonType="PushButton" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True">
                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
     <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Charity" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" 
            UniqueName="column3" DataType="System.String" DataField="charity" ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
         <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="VIN" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column6 column" 
            UniqueName="column7" DataType="System.String" DataField="vin" >
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
             </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Year" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" 
            UniqueName="column2" DataType="System.Int32" DataField="year">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Make" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" 
            UniqueName="column" DataType="System.String" DataField="make">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Model" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column1" DataType="System.String" DataField="model">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>            
             <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Last Update" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column5" DataType="System.DateTime" DataField="date" ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
         <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Min. Bid" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column8" DataType="System.Decimal" DataField="bid" DataFormatString="{0:C}" >
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="Sale Price" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column6" DataType="System.Decimal" DataField="salePrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" Display="False">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="unsoldNotesColumn" DataType="System.String" DataField="note" Display="True">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Latest Status" ItemStyle-Width="240px">


                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>

                        </ItemTemplate>


                        <EditItemTemplate>

                            <telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="pendingVehiclesRadGridupdateComboBox" DataTextField="Status" 

                                DataValueField="ID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" >

                            </telerik:RadComboBox>                          

                        </EditItemTemplate>


<ItemStyle Width="240px"></ItemStyle>


                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn FooterText="EditCommand footer" UniqueName="pendingVehiclesRadGridEditCommandColumn"

                        HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" UpdateText="Update">

<HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>

                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>



    </Columns>

<EditFormSettings EditColumn-DataType="System.String">
<EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
</EditFormSettings>
</MasterTableView>

<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Please show the whole XAML of your RadGrid. I think there is something wrong with your command buttons.

Comment: @modiX I'm fairly new here... how can I post the entire thing in comments?  Sorry :(

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 you can edit your question instead of putting it in the comments

Comment: Things to check: 1) You're using NeedDataSource correctly and your'e not manually binding the RadGrid anywhere else in your code 2) your RadGrid markup is correct

Comment: @Scotty I can certainly check that, but would it cause the update command to not fire at all?

Comment: @modiX Added my XAML... thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 yes if you're manually binding your grid on page load for example

Comment: @Scotty That I'm not doing... only binding in the needdatasource events and after calling filtering queries, all of which has been working previously.  Annoying as heck :S

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 Sorry, I actually had a typo and meant the XML of ASPX, you served, thanks. (I was at WPF with my head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reconstruct your example and it worked:

ASPX:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="pendingVehiclesRadGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True"
    DataMember="ID"
    OnNeedDataSource="pendingVehiclesRadGrid_NeedDataSource"
    OnUpdateCommand="pendingVehiclesRadGrid_UpdateCommand" PageSize="20"
    OnItemCommand="pendingVehiclesRadGrid_ItemCommand">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="status,charity,make,model,year,vin,date,id,salePrice,bid,note"
        EditMode="EditForms">

        <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>

        <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" HeaderStyle-Width="20px" />

        <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" HeaderStyle-Width="20px" />

        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="History" Text="History" UniqueName="detailBtn" HeaderText="History" HeaderButtonType="PushButton" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Charity" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" UniqueName="column3" DataType="System.String" DataField="charity" ReadOnly="True" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="VIN" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column6 column" UniqueName="column7" DataType="System.String" DataField="vin" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Year" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" UniqueName="column2" DataType="System.Int32" DataField="year" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Make" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" UniqueName="column" DataType="System.String" DataField="make" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Model" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" UniqueName="column1" DataType="System.String" DataField="model" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Last Update" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" UniqueName="column5" DataType="System.DateTime" DataField="date" ReadOnly="True" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Min. Bid" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" UniqueName="column8" DataType="System.Decimal" DataField="bid" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Sale Price" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" UniqueName="column6" DataType="System.Decimal" DataField="salePrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" Display="False" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" UniqueName="unsoldNotesColumn" DataType="System.String" DataField="note" Display="True" />
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Latest Status" ItemStyle-Width="240px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <%-- I have to outcomment this, because I don't have any LinqDataSource1 available --%>
                    <%--<telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="pendingVehiclesRadGridupdateComboBox" DataTextField="Status"
                        DataValueField="ID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>--%>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn FooterText="EditCommand footer" UniqueName="pendingVehiclesRadGridEditCommandColumn" HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" UpdateText="Update" />
        </Columns>

        <EditFormSettings EditColumn-DataType="System.String">
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column" />
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>

    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

```
protected void pendingVehiclesRadGrid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    this.pendingVehiclesRadGrid.DataSource = new List<object> {
        new {
            id = 1,
            charity = "charity1",
            vin = "vin1",
            year = 2015,
            make = "make1",
            model = "model1",
            date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1),
            bid = (decimal)12000.00,
            salePrice = (decimal)14469.95,
            note = "a new car",
            Status = "NOT SOLD"
        },
        new {
            id = 2,
            charity = "charity2",
            vin = "vin2",
            year = 1967,
            make = "make2",
            model = "model2",
            date = DateTime.Now,
            bid = (decimal)14000.00,
            salePrice = (decimal)19469.95,
            note = "an oldtimer",
            Status = "NOT SOLD"
        }
    };
}

protected void pendingVehiclesRadGrid_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This will be reached!"); // I've put the breakpoint here
}

protected void pendingVehiclesRadGrid_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

As you can see I've removed some unnecessary markup, but this was not the problem source. I also had to remove the `RadComboBox` in your `EditItemTemplate`, because I cannot use the `LinqDataSource1`.

But to be clear: **I don't know why it's not working at you, but I hope this will help you to track the issue.**

Try to out-comment the `RadComboBox` at you, too. See if this is the problem source. If not, you might do any mistake in your code behind, maybe on the data binding itself.

If you cannot track the problem, try to isolate the problem in an own solution. Nail it down by using hard coded data (like on my example). If the problem persists, post all the code from your test solution or share the solution itself **without** the Telerik components (!)

Comment: Thank you VERY much... I know how much time you invested in helping me!  I'm going to tackle this and see if in fact the problem is in the combobox.  I'm completely baffled about this especially since it did originally work and I can't think of anything I changed that would account for this.  I'll keep you posted!

Thanks again... :)

Comment: So I'm afraid I'm getting nowhere fast.  I tried commenting out the combobox, which created all sorts of exceptions about setting properties on a null object even after I tried finding and commenting out references to the combobox throughout.  I tried adding a dropdown list instead and that "seems" to not have solved the problem.  I'm really beating my brains out over this... any other tips/suggestions?  

Thank you in any event for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

@modiX  Okay... thank you sincerely, again, for your help.  I have yet to figure out the problem but after beating my head against it for two days I realized that at one point, this did all work and perhaps somewhere in all the other work I did on the form, I broke it and didn't realize it until it was too late.  So, I started cutting out each of the three grids and their code behind one at a time and pasting them into a fresh new page.  And... they work.

No clue what "feature" caused them to break but I'm willing to call this a victory and move on... more cautiously ;)

Thank you once again for your time and kind assistance!

Comment: This should not be an answer, it should be just an comment on my answer, since you cannot provide any solution to your case. Whatsoever, great you solved it, though, magically disappearing problems make me nervous, since they can come back in anytime, because you don't know what caused them to appear. I recommend your team to use a subversion control software to be able to track changes, easily. You're welcome! :)

Comment: @modiX I agree with you on all points... I only entered it as an answer because the "case is closed".  And again... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I've been struggling with it, and have something that doesn't make sense, but seems to work.

I added `<ClientEvents OnRowDeleting="void 0" />` to `ClientSettings` under the RadGrid, and it seems to work. It also keeps the RadGrid at its full normal size; it was getting cut in half for no apparent reason, with the scroll bar halfway up.

This is supposed to fire Javascript when deleting a record, but I have no need for it to actually DO that. Hence, the `void 0` to make it do nothing.

I have no explanation for why it is working as it is, which is frustrating, but it at least works better now.